# Why does image get covered up in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

I put an image into the following wordpress site:

http://sofrahomemadefood.com/menu/

The image is big. Therefore, it runs over its container. It gets covered up by the next region as the following image shows:

[image: Image gets covered up by the surrounding region]

I would like to learn the reason of this and how to prevent the image being covered up?

Comment: I add `width:100%` to class `.alignnone` and it fit in container. Try it.

Comment: Is it a background image or an `<img>` tag?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks It is an <img> tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is this chunk of html:

```
<img class="alignnone" title="Menu" src="http://i.imgur.com/OKRf1h.jpg" alt="" width="1024" height="663">
```

(that's the embedded image, notice the width and height attributes)

You can fix it with:

```
img.alignnone{
    width: auto; /*You may want to flag this !important for some browsers*/
    height: auto; /*You may want to flag this !important for some browsers*/
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

What this does:

- The image's nautral aspect ratio is preserved by the use of `width:auto` and `height:auto`
- The image is prevented from breaking out of the bounds of it's parent element by `max-height:100%` and `max-width:100%`

On a side note:

For people who always want the image to scale to the width/height of the parent, preserving aspect ratio: You can use `min-width:100%` (for width) or `min-height:100%` for height, with `width:auto` and `height:auto` to preserve the ratio.

If you would rather keep the image at size and let it flow out of the content area, you can remove `overflow:hidden` from the `div.maincontent` selector on line 202 of style.css.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed this solved the problem. But it scaled down the image a bit. Is it possible to let the image overflow the surrounding region?

Comment: Yes, check the last paragraph of the answer.